# Exporting layers from ArcGIS into PostGIS while preserving attributes such as color

Tags: arcgis-desktop, postgis, geoserver, vector, fields-attributes

I have managed to import/convert a KML into ArcGIS 10.0 (ArcMap) using the built-in conversion tools and now have a series of layers. Next, I export these layers to a PostGIS database using the following command:

```
ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG:'host=localhost port=12345 dbname=mydb user=removed password=removed' Roads.gdb -progress --config PG_USE_COPY YES
```

Note that when doing so, four separate layers are stored as a single layer in PostGIS - I'm unsure whether or not that is relevant. Anyhow, next, I use GeoServer with the PostGIS database as a store to serve the layer using WMS, and have a Leaflet client display the tiles overlaid on various other tiles.

Somewhere in this process all color attributes from the data are apparently removed (The data are a set of lines over roads, colored based upon speed limit - each color is a separate ArcGIS layer).

How can I preserve the attributes of my data? I have access to ArcGIS Desktop, PostGIS,  OGR/GDAL, and GeoServer.

Comment: PostGIS is just a geo-spatial component of PostgreSQL database.  Databases typically do not store layer styles.  Styling is usually performed on the client side (e.g. ArcMap, QGIS, Leaflet, OpenLayers...etc), or styled via a GIS server (e.g. ArcGIS server or GeoServer) as a WMS.

Comment: I'm sorry, I must be tired as I left that out - I am using GeoServer's WMS service [original question heavily edited]. How might I convey the layer styles to GeoServer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following program [ArcMap2SLDConverter](http://arcmap2sld.i3mainz.hs-mainz.de/ArcMap2SLDConverter_Eng.htm) will generate an SLD file from an ArcGIS Map - but you must have ArcGIS installed and running to do so.

This SLD can then be uploaded to GeoServer, and used to style the corresponding layer.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I have not found a method for creating SLD files in ArcMap for GeoServer use.  There are some alternative app. options:

- Udig
- QGIS
- GeoExplorer
- GeoServer admin SLD editor

Comment: Thanks. I'll post a new question regarding the best way to go from KML -> PostGIS / GeoServer while preserving styles.