# Preserving styles when going from KML to WMS

Tags: postgis, geoserver, wms, kml, style

I'm currently losing styling information somewhere along my chain of applications:

```
KML -> ArcGIS Layer (via ArcGIS Desktop)
ArcGIS .gdb -> PostGIS via ogr2ogr
PostGIS -> GeoServer
GeoServer -> Leaflet via WMS service
```

How might I preserve styling information when serving data originally stored as a KML via WMS? I have found no way to export styles from a KML into SLDs.

If this can natively be done through a different type of GIS Server, please advise.

Comment: "ArcGIS Layer" ought to be "file geodatabase" (a layer is the presentation ruleset of a feature class, which can have any source).  "Styling" is not part of data in conventional GIS applications, which is most of your problem.

Comment: Correct, the ArcGIS layer is actually a .gdb. So if styling is not traditionally part of the data, are there any tools for creating style descriptors from kml?

Comment: Your question should be rewritten to ask how to map KML styling to GeoServer (with a data source of PostgreSQL geometry).  The fact that the geometry passes through FGDB is incidental.

Comment: How does this question differ from [your previous one](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141771/exporting-layers-from-arcgis-into-postgis-while-preserving-attributes-such-as-co)?

Comment: The intent of this question was to see how one might serve a KML file via WMS, whereas the previous question was specific to GeoServer. I can clarify this question to better reflect the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently this can't be done natively, as far as I know. The thread here: [Converting ArcGIS layer style to Styled Layer Descriptor (SLD) file?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3755/converting-arcgis-layer-style-to-styled-layer-descriptor-sld-file) has some info on getting the styles from ESRI lyr to a sld, which is basically what you want, but it's not very smooth (or cheap for arc2earth).

I think a more elegant solution is waiting to be developed.

Comment: I think you're right about this ability not existing natively. By using ArcGIS, I'm able to go from LYR to SLD using this tool: http://arcmap2sld.i3mainz.hs-mainz.de/ArcMap2SLDConverter_Eng.htm , but haven't found a way to go from KML->LYR while preserving styling information (although the documentation on the ArcGIS KML->LYR seems to state that it should..). For the time being, I'm manually re-creating an approximate styling in ArcGIS. grumble!